# Referring class local variable inside of a method which located in the object that located in the same class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Here is the sample code.

```
class TestClass {
    constructor() {
        let question = "How could I refer this variable inside of the nested object?"
    }
}

TestClass.prototype.category = {
    validate : function () {
        return true;
    }
    , read : function () {
        // this in here is not TestClass. How could I refer TestClass Instance(caller) in strict mode ?
        console.log('Inside of TestClass.prototype.category.read', this);
        if(this.validate) {
            console.log('I would like to refer TestClass.question', this.question);
        }
    }
}

TestClass.prototype.readCategory = function () {
    this.category.read();
}
```

Then I do something like below in chrome editor console.

```
var test = new TestClass();
test.readCategory();

// result is like below
I would like to refer TestClass.question undefined
```

As far as I know, I presume like

1. When using the `new` keyword, I will generate an instance which contains `question` variable and the methods which I pushed into `prototype`
2. Then it will execute `readCategory()`, it calls `instance.category.read` but at this moment, `this` keyword will point `instance.read` Object, not the `TestClass` instance. So `this.question` will be an `undefined` value.
3. So here's the question, how could I able to access the caller(or Class instance) variable?

I found out that when we use `class`, unable to use `this.caller`.(automatically applied strict mode).

How would I access the class variable in this situation? Thanx.

Comment: The `question` variable is available only within the scope of `constructor` and I mean literally the scope there - the area surrounded by `{` and `}`. Outside of that, you won't have access to `question`. It also certainly won't be added as a property to the object, because it's a local variable.

Comment: Why do you want `category` to be a separate object?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The real js file has more complexed functions and variables and I want to group those members into the functional groups which has the same purpose.

Comment: Then don't you want a completely separate class, say `PartialFunctionalityA` and `PartialFunctionalityB` and then simply make `TestClass` have an *instance* of each and, if needed, forward calls to them. Say, `testClassInstance.calculateSomething = (someVar) => this.partialFunctionalityAInstance.calculateSomething(someVar)`. This is typically called *delegation* and it's used as part of the composition concept in OOP.

Comment: @JuneyoungOh - ^^ what vlaz said. :-)

Comment: @vlaz Thanks for the advice. Maybe I should accept your advice. However, when I first make this class, its functionality was quite clear. It just does execute some ajax request and stores that into the localStorage. But as time goes there become too many APIs, so I would like to divide into small pieces by API target - like brands, categories and so on.

Comment: It sounds like you need something like [the Facade pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, your `category` variable is completely private to the constructor. Once the constructor returns, it's gone.

Your structure is fairly unusual, but if you really need `category` to be a subordinate object, but you still want it to have access to `TestClass` instance it's part of, you might use arrow functions created in the constructor to achieve that, see comments:

```
class TestClass {
    constructor() {
        // Make question a property
        this.question = "How could I refer this variable inside of the nested object?"
        // Make category an instance property using arrow functions
        this.category = {
            validate : () => {
                return true;
            }
            , read : () => {
                console.log('Inside of TestClass.prototype.category.read', this);
                if(this.category.validate()) { // <=== Need to add `category.` and `()`
                    console.log('I would like to refer TestClass.question', this.question);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    // No reason to define this outside the `class` construct, make it a method
    readCategory() {
        this.category.read();
    }
}
```

Using the [class fields proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) (currently at Stage 3, so you'll need to transpile), you can also write that like this:

```
class TestClass {
    // Make category an instance property using arrow functions
    category = {
        validate : () => {
            return true;
        }
        , read : () => {
            console.log('Inside of TestClass.prototype.category.read', this);
            if(this.category.validate()) { // <=== Need to add `category.` and `()`
                console.log('I would like to refer TestClass.question', this.question);
            }
        }
    };

    constructor() {
        // Make question a property
        this.question = "How could I refer this variable inside of the nested object?"
    }

    // No reason to define this outside the `class` construct, make it a method
    readCategory() {
        this.category.read();
    }
}
```

That's effectively the same thing as the first example; field initializers are executed as though within the constructor.

If you don't want `question` to be a property on the instance, since those are arrow functions defined in the constructor, you could leave it as a local variable they close over:

```
class TestClass {
    constructor() {
        let question = "How could I refer this variable inside of the nested object?"

        this.category = {
            validate : () => {
                return true;
            }
            , read : () => {
                console.log('Inside of TestClass.prototype.category.read', this);
                if(this.category.validate()) {
                    console.log('I would like to refer TestClass.question', question); // <== No `this.`
                }
            }
        };
    }

    readCategory() {
        this.category.read();
    }
}
```

Comment: Good insight! I forgot the scope problem. Anyway, is it able to move `this.category` into `readCategory` scope level? It looks the constructor handle too much logic to me - I am so new in javascript.

Comment: @JuneyoungOh - You can make it seem like it does less using the class fields syntax (I've added it above, in the middle because that's where it fit), but again, I wouldn't do it this way. Make them separate pieces you aggregate together, rather than one big class.